# Powershell send file as attachment of a mail

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sendmail

I need to check if a file exist into a path.

if yes, I need to send it as attachment of mail.

this my code now:

```
$file='STREAM_preg.txt'
$pathfile ='c:\Users\root\Desktop'
$dest ='C:\Users\root\Desktop\test'

cd $pathfile
if(Test-Path $file){
        $datestamp = get-date -uformat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
    Copy-Item $file $dest\$datestamp"_"$file
    $new_file = echo $datestamp"_"$file
    echo $new_file
      # Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer xxxxxxxxxx -To pluto@pippo.com -From preg_new_stream@pippo.com -Subject "test mail" -Body "file name is: $new_file"
}else{
        echo false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Send-Mailmessage` accepts file paths to attach.

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer xxxxxxxxxx -To pluto@pippo.com -From preg_new_stream@pippo.com -Subject "test mail" -Body "file name is: $new_file" -attachment $new_file
```

Comment: Just for completeness:
-Attachments string[]
       The path and file names of files to be attached to the email message. Use this parameter or pipe the path/file names.

Answer (score 0):

Send-mailmessage takes one or more file paths as pipeline input for attachements.  Just pipe the file path into that send-meailmessage command, and it's get sent as an attachment to the email.